# How to get the keys of an array of object? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
var inputData = [{
  name: 'Nick',
  achievements: 158,
  points: 14730
}, {
  name: 'Jordan',
  achievements: '175',
  points: '16375'
}, {
  name: 'Ramon',
  achievements: '55',
  points: '2025'
}];


var outputData = inputData.map(function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key) { 
    return obj[key];
   });
});

 console.log(JSON.stringify(outputData));
```

This gives result as

```
 [["Nick",158,14730], 
 ["Jordan","175","16375"], 
 ["Ramon","55","2025"]]
```

Desired output

```
 [["name", "achievements", "points"],
 ["Nick", "158", "14730"],
 ["Jordan", "175", "16375"],
 ["Ramon", "55", "2025"]]
```

Basically i need my data in this format to generate CSV. So I am converting my array of objects to array of array. The first row of the array of array will contain the keys, while the next rows will contain the values.

I don't want to use Lodash or Jquery. Iam looking for a solution in Plain Vanilla JS

Comment: You're already using `Object.keys()` - why doesn't that work?

Comment: Use `Object.keys(obj)` for keys and `Object.value(obj)` for value.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
const outputData = [Object.keys(inputData[0]), ...inputData.map(Object.values)];
```

though, you'd want some `.length`-check. And you'll get some strange results if the objects are of different *shape*.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputData = [{
  name: 'Nick',
  achievements: 158,
  points: 14730
}, {
  name: 'Jordan',
  achievements: '175',
  points: '16375'
}, {
  name: 'Ramon',
  achievements: '55',
  points: '2025'
}];


var outputData = inputData.reduce((acc,obj,i) => {
  if(i == 0) acc.push(Object.keys(obj));
  acc.push(Object.values(obj));
  return acc;
},[]);

 console.log(JSON.stringify(outputData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code -

```
var inputData = [{
name: 'Nick',
achievements: 158,
points: 14730
 }, {
name: 'Jordan',
achievements: '175',
points: '16375'
 }, {
name: 'Ramon',
achievements: '55',
points: '2025'
}];


var outputData = inputData.map(function(obj) {
 return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) { 
return obj[key];
   });
 });
outputData.unshift(Object.keys(inputData[0]))
 console.log(JSON.stringify(outputData));
```

only `outputData.unshift(Object.keys(inputData[0]))` is added and `sort()` method is removed in your existing code.